# Underscore.js - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) while generating template with variables

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to learn Backbone.js with Underscore.js and got into trouble. I'm using Grails as a server framework, so the Underscore.js syntax <%= %> is not possible. I want to change it to {{}} style. My Javascripts are separated in many files, each representing either a View or Model for every objects I need. Here is the code for my View:

```
$(function () {

    _.templateSettings = {
        interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
        evaluate : /\{!(.+?)!\}/g
    };

    APP = window.APP || {};

    APP.PlaceView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:function () {
            this.render();
        },
        el:"#place-form",
        formTemplate:_.template($('#search-template').html()),
        render:function () {
            //Pass variables in using Underscore.js Template
            var variables = { street:"Ulica" };

            this.$el.html(this.formTemplate({ "street":"Ulica" }));
        }
    });

    var view = new APP.PlaceView();
});
```

And the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="search-template">
    <!-- Access template variables with {{ }} -->
    <label>{{ street }}</label>
    <input type="text" id="search_input"/>
    <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search"/>
</script>
```

This code throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) error. But when I delete the _.templateSettings part, everything is ok, but I don't have the variables.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error, I'm using handlebar's syntax because I'm using HAML, any idea how you solved this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's showing that error because of this line:

```
<!-- Access template variables with {{ }} -->
```

Underscore is trying to replace that with a variable that doesn't exist, thus throwing an error.

Comment: this was driving me crazy! It shouldn't be in the sample code </rant>